# positioning custom checkbox icon

Tags: css, checkbox

I made a custom checkbox with css. For the checked icon i use Google's material icons. Now the only problem is that the icon is not vertically centered. How do I do that?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember">
<label for="remember">Angemeldet bleiben</label>
```

CSS:

```
/* Basic Styling
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label,
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
input[type="radio"] + label:after,
input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Radios
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.4em #fafafa, inset 0 0 0 1em #fafafa;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.4em #fafafa, inset 0 0 0 1em #eee;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #2196F3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.4em #fafafa, inset 0 0 0 1em #2196F3;
}

/* Checkboxes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-size: 18px;
  content: '\E876';
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fafafa;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:hover:before {
  color: #eee;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  color: #2196F3;
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Just make the line-height of the checkbox label match the height of the checkbox itself.

Comment: thanks, works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height property.

```
    input[type="radio"] + label:before,
    input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
    input[type="radio"] + label:after,
    input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {line-height: 19px;}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/k3zLj0w4/

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do that, but in my opinion, the best solution is with **CSS vertical-align Property**.

Required reading on [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) link.